# Is the statement true: $\cos x\cos 2x\cos 4x=1/4\cos 3x$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to show that $\cos x\cos 2x\cos 4x=1/4\cos 3x$?

I have tried  by $\cos x\cos 2x\cos 4x=\frac{1}{2}\cos x[2\cos 2x\cos 4x]$.
$=\frac{1}{2}\cos x[\cos 6x+\cos 2x]$.
$=\frac{1}{4}[2\cos x\cos 6x+2\cos x\cos 2x]$
But it is not going to the required result.

Updated: I found it here.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "here"? Are we supposed to recognize the source from that picture?

Comment: I still have no idea what the book is saying.

Answer (score 10):

No it's false, try it with $x=0$.